# Find filename in Ansible and Save to a file

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

How can I take filename from a specific directory and use it as a variable?
Then I'll use this variable to copy a new file with variable filename

For example: In the directory `/home/user1/test/` there is always only one file named `test1` or some other name.
I need to extract the filename (test1) from this path to some variable

```
- hosts: linux
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: Ansible find file examples
    find:
     paths: /home/user1/test/
    register: files_matched

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ files_matched.files }}"

  - name: "Save find results to file"
    copy:
      content: "{{ files_matched.files }}"
      dest: "/tmp/find_result.txt"
```

Then I've should get "test1" as variable and use it in the new filename in this code:

```
      copy:
        src: /home/myuser/myfile
        dest: "{{ item.dest }}"
        owner: root
        group: root
        mode: 0666
      with_items:
        - { dest: '/home/user2/test/{{ files_matched }}' }
```

As result of first script i've got:

```
: 0, "ischr": false, "wusr": true, "xoth": false, "islnk": false, "nlink": 1, "issock": false, "rgrp": true, "gr_name": "root", "path": "/home/user1/test/test1", "xusr":
false, "atime": 1564553299.6092095, "isdir": false, "ctime": 1564553304.7172158, "isblk": false, "xgrp": false, "dev": 2050, "wgrp": false, "isfifo": false, "mode": "0644
", "rusr": true}]
```

But i need only `test1` part as result, not this all.
Thank you!

Comment: If you are sure that In the directory /home/user1/test/ will always have only one file, then use this content: "{{ files_matched.files[0].path }}" . this will provide you the full path of the file as output (/home/user2/test/test1).

Comment: Thank you! Thats working!
And then how can I get (test1) output from (/home/user1/test/test1)?

Answer (score 0):

> Q: "How can I take filename from a specific directory and use it as a variable?'

A: Given the tree

```
$ tree /home/user1/test/
/home/user1/test/
├── test1
├── test2
└── test3
```

the tasks below

```
- find:
    paths: /home/user1/test/
  register: files_matched
- debug:
    msg: "{{ '/home/user2/test/' ~ item|basename }}"
  loop: "{{ files_matched.files|json_query('[*].path') }}
```

give

```
"msg": "/home/user2/test/test1"
"msg": "/home/user2/test/test3"
"msg": "/home/user2/test/test2"
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are expecting something like this. this will save the list of files under the specified directory into the /tmp/find_result.txt. I hope from here you can proceed.

```
---
- name: find file
  hosts: linux
  tasks:
  - name: Ansible find file examples
    find:
     paths: /home/user1/test/
    register: files_matched

  - name: "Save find results to file"
    lineinfile:
      line: "{{ item.path }}"
      path: "/tmp/find_result.txt"
      create: yes
    loop: "{{ files_matched.files | flatten }}"
```

note: make sure that you delete the /tmp/find_result.txt once your task completed.

if you want to store only the filename not the entire path, then replace `line: "{{ item.path }}"` with `line: "{{ item.path | basename }}"`